# “In the way quoted” or “the way in which quoted”

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbials

> I wouldn't use 'degree of' in the way quoted in the Cambridge Corpus

Shouldn’t it be “I wouldn’t use ‘degree of’ the way in which it is quoted in the Cambridge Corpus”?

[Why do concrete nouns not follow “a degree of”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/294253/why-do-concrete-nouns-not-follow-a-degree-of?noredirect=1#comment547589_294253)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is fine as it is. It is formal style which often makes use of reduced relative clauses:

> Relative clauses can be reduced to shorter forms if the relative clause modifies the subject of a sentence. Relative clause reduction refers to *removing a relative pronoun to reduce*:
>
> - An adjective - person ***who was happy***: ***happy** person*
> - An adjective phrase - man ***who was responsible for***: man ***responsible** for*
> - A prepositional phrase - boxes ***that are under the counter***: boxes ***under the counter***
> - A past participle - student ***that was elected president:*** student ***elected** president* **[this is the category to which your sentence belongs to]**
> - A present participle - people ***who are working on the report***: people ***working** on the report* ([Thought.Co](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107))

You have understood it correctly as meaning:

> I wouldn’t use ‘degree of’ in the way ***[in which it is]*** quoted in the Cambridge Corpus.

*In which it is* was omitted for concision's sake which is important in formal style.

Comment: Can I use “in the quoted way” instead of “in the way in which it is quoted”? Or should I use “in the way quoted”?

Comment: You can, if nothing follows after. But as your sentence stands, it does state _where_ the quoting is done: "in the way quoted **in the Cambridge Corpus**". So I would keep it as it is.

Comment: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/interestedly Is it in a same sense?

Comment: No, there _interested_ is a simple adjective. In your sentence, _quoted_ is clearly a past participle of "quote" in a _**passive reduced relative clause**_.

Comment: Thank you so much.